# How do I decode fernet encryption in R?

Tags: r, fernet

I have a string that was encrypted in python using the Fernet algorithm (https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/). How can I read this value in R?

Here's the python code which gives some example data

```
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(b"ThisIsTheRealKeyItIsAVeryGoodOne")
fernet = Fernet(key)
fernet.encrypt(b"hello")
```

So a sample input string is

```
gAAAAABkCluAsIXI905vOlZsut1CvVtboIZ2_NHalTQLbsZv_ogl0reBBWg4v0UlTcg5aqMRzBfFxKBGVGUHYqepeNQb8wpfgQ==
```

And I want to get "hello" back out given the key "ThisIsTheRealKeyItIsAVeryGoodOne" and the encrypted string above. How can I decode this value in R?

I do know that each time I run the python code a different output is produced, but I assume they can all be coded in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find an R package that would do the encryption automatically for you in R, but It's possible to put together code using many of the encryption features of `openssl`. Let's define a few helper functions

```
library(openssl)

url_unsafe <- function(x) gsub("_", "/" ,gsub("-", "+", x, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)
url_safe <- function(x) gsub("/", "_" ,gsub("+", "-", x, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)

split_raw_message <- function(token) {
  if (is.character(token)) {
    bytes <- openssl::base64_decode(url_unsafe(token))
  } else if (is.raw(token)) {
    bytes <- token
  } else {
    stop("token should be base64 encoded string or raw vector")
  }
  stopifnot("message too short"=length(bytes)>1+8+16+23)
  stopifnot("missing magic number"=bytes[1]==0x80)
  list(
    magic = bytes[1],
    ts = bytes[2:9],
    iv = bytes[10:25],
    payload = bytes[26:(length(bytes)-32)],
    signature = utils::tail(bytes, 32)
  )
}

validate_signature <- function(message, key) {
  all(as.raw(openssl::sha256(with(message, c(magic, ts, iv,  payload)), key=key)) == message$signature)
}

sign_message <- function(message, key) {
  message$signature <- as.raw(openssl::sha256(with(message, as.raw(c(magic, ts, iv, payload))), key=key))
  message
}

decode_message_raw <- function(encrypted_string, keys) {
  message <- split_raw_message(encrypted_string)
  stopifnot(validate_signature(message, keys$sign))
  list(
    content = rawToChar(openssl::aes_cbc_decrypt(message$payload, keys$encrypt, iv = message$iv)),
    ts = as.POSIXct(readBin(message$ts, "integer", n=1, size=8, endian = "big"), origin="1970-01-01")
  )
}

decode_message <- function(encrypted_string, keys) {
  decode_message_raw(encrypted_string, keys)$content
}

build_message <- function(content, keys, iv=openssl::rand_bytes(16), ts=Sys.time()) {
  if (inherits(ts, "POSIXt")) {
    ts <- writeBin(as.numeric(ts), raw(0), size=8, endian="big")
  }
  message <- list(
    magic = as.raw(0x80),
    ts = ts,
    iv = as.raw(iv),
    payload = c(openssl::aes_cbc_encrypt(charToRaw(content), keys$encrypt, iv = iv))
  )
  message <- sign_message(message, keys$sign)
  message
}

encode_message <- function(content, keys) {
  message <- build_message(content, keys)
  url_safe(openssl::base64_encode(with(message, c(magic, ts, iv, payload, signature))))
}
```

The main function you need to decode the message is `decode_message`. Note that the python fernet key is actually made up of two parts. So in R we will split the 32 bit key into the encrytion part and the signing part

```
fernet_keys <- list(
  sign = charToRaw("ThisIsTheRealKey"),
  encrypt = charToRaw("ItIsAVeryGoodOne")
)
```

Now we can decode the message.

```
encoded <- "gAAAAABkCluAsIXI905vOlZsut1CvVtboIZ2_NHalTQLbsZv_ogl0reBBWg4v0UlTcg5aqMRzBfFxKBGVGUHYqepeNQb8wpfgQ=="
decode_message(encoded, fernet_keys)
# [1] "hello"
```

We can also encode values in R, but note that it's unlikely you will get the exact same output because the encoded value uses a random initialization vector each time and a timestamp. Note this decoding function doesn't check the timestamp, but if you use `decode_message_raw` rather than `decode_message` you can get the timestamp and use that to decide if you want to trust the message.

Comment: Do you often ask and self-answer a question at the same time? What's your intent if you know the answer? (Congrats on 200k, btw!)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. 200K is cool, though the rate of increase has really slowed down. I usually will post and self answer if it was something I was searching for but couldn't find on the internet. It's pretty common that I still search for things and find my own answers from years ago to be helpful.  Mostly just a way to get the info out there and make it searchable if I think there's a reasonable chance it will help others as well. Gotta practice writing good questions as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks MrFlick for an excellent working answer. I wrapped that solution into an R6 for easy usage:

```
Fernet <- R6::R6Class(
  lock_objects = FALSE,
  public = list(
    initialize = function(){
            
    },
    
    set_key = function(key){
    
      stopifnot(is.character(key))
      stopifnot(nchar(key) == 32)
      
      self$fernet_keys <- list(
        sign = charToRaw(substr(key, 1, 16)),
        encrypt = charToRaw(substr(key, 17, 32))
      )
    
    },
    
    decode_message = function(encrypted_string) {

      private$decode_message_raw(encrypted_string, self$fernet_keys)$content
    },
    
    encode_message = function(content) {
      message <- private$build_message(content, self$fernet_keys)
      
      private$url_safe(openssl::base64_encode(with(message, c(magic, ts, iv, payload, signature))))
    }
    
  ),
  
  
  
  private = list(
    url_unsafe = function(x) gsub("_", "/" ,gsub("-", "+", x, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE),
    url_safe = function(x) gsub("/", "_" ,gsub("+", "-", x, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE),
    
    split_raw_message = function(token) {
      
      if (is.character(token)) {
        bytes <- openssl::base64_decode(private$url_unsafe(token))
      } else if (is.raw(token)) {
        bytes <- token
      } else {
        stop("token should be base64 encoded string or raw vector")
      }
      
      stopifnot("message too short"=length(bytes)>1+8+16+23)
      stopifnot("missing magic number"=bytes[1]==0x80)
      list(
        magic = bytes[1],
        ts = bytes[2:9],
        iv = bytes[10:25],
        payload = bytes[26:(length(bytes)-32)],
        signature = utils::tail(bytes, 32)
      )
    },
    
    validate_signature = function(message, key) {
      all(as.raw(openssl::sha256(with(message, c(magic, ts, iv,  payload)), key=key)) == message$signature)
    },
    
    sign_message = function(message, key) {
      message$signature <- as.raw(openssl::sha256(with(message, as.raw(c(magic, ts, iv, payload))), key=key))
      message
    },
    
    decode_message_raw = function(encrypted_string, keys) {
      
      message <- private$split_raw_message(encrypted_string)
      stopifnot(private$validate_signature(message, keys$sign))
      
      list(
        content = rawToChar(openssl::aes_cbc_decrypt(message$payload, keys$encrypt, iv = message$iv)),
        ts = as.POSIXct(readBin(message$ts, "integer", n=1, size=8, endian = "big"), origin="1970-01-01")
      )
    },
    
    
    
    build_message = function(content, keys, iv=openssl::rand_bytes(16), ts=Sys.time()) {
      if (inherits(ts, "POSIXt")) {
        ts <- writeBin(as.numeric(ts), raw(0), size=8, endian="big")
      }
      message <- list(
        magic = as.raw(0x80),
        ts = ts,
        iv = as.raw(iv),
        payload = c(openssl::aes_cbc_encrypt(charToRaw(content), keys$encrypt, iv = iv))
      )
      message <- private$sign_message(message, keys$sign)
      message
    }
    
    
  )
  
  
)
```

And a test:

```
key <- "ThisIsTheRealKeyItIsAVeryGoodOne"
encoded_text <- "gAAAAABkCluAsIXI905vOlZsut1CvVtboIZ2_NHalTQLbsZv_ogl0reBBWg4v0UlTcg5aqMRzBfFxKBGVGUHYqepeNQb8wpfgQ=="

fern <- Fernet$new()
fern$set_key(key)

fern$decode_message(encoded_text)
```

gives `hello`